# Too many redirects to external server I don't know

Tags: performance, external

Yesterday I noticed that a page on my website wouldn't load properly anymore and it looks like www.wylei.com is causing this problem, one of their services is "Predictive Content".

[Check out the console errors I see in Chrome here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8GFe.jpg)

I did quit some digging in my code but I have not found the source of the problem. My only vague lead is Wylei partnered with Amazon AWS.

Do you have any idea why this Wylei stuff is bugging me and how I can get rid of it?

The page I'm referring to is http://zitecraft.com/sites/netherlands/amsterdam/de-pijp/tweede-van-der-helststraat-3/glouglou/3666/home/4.html/NL

Comment: The link to your site isn't working. If I follow the https link you posted I get a 404. When I load http://zitecraft.com/sites/netherlands/amsterdam/de-pijp/tweede-van-der-helststraat-3/glouglou/3666/home/4.html/NL#contact the page loads and no errors are shown.

Comment: Sorry about that Matt, I changed the https to http now. Thanks for testing.

Comment: Yes, but the page doesn't show any errors in the console.